# Add an external link in the admin dashboard

Tags: shopify

[image: A link in Shopify admin Panel]

I am developing an app and need an external **LINK** in Shopify admin panel like given picture.

where to add code snippet for the link? Do i need to add a script via API or changing in theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called "Application links". You can setup these links at your partner dashboard.

1. Go to https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/
2. Click on 'Apps' tab
3. Click on the application name you want to have an application link
4. Click on "Edit App Details"
5. Scroll down, there is "Application links" section